# Custom selection in row with vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

My problem is pretty straight-forward: how do I define the range from a certain cell to the end of the row?

If you would know what am I trying to achieve, you would understand the situation better: I want to sort rows individually but every row's datas start at 17. column, so I'm trying to make the sorting from 17. column to end of the column count.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Range(Cells(iRow,17), Cells(iRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))`, where `iRow` is the current row index

Comment: Also this worked for me too. Depending on the performance of these code, I am going to use one of them. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining range in VBA: `Dim rng As Range`.

Setting range (since it's *object*, you must use `Set` keyword): `Set rng = Range("A1:B2")`
or

`Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2))` - both are equivalent.

So, if you want to specify custom range in ONE row starting from 17th column, you must also know where the rows ends, you can do that in two ways:

```
Dim lastCol As Long
lastCol = Cells(rowNumber, 17).End(xlToRight).Column
'alternative, but not equivalent
lastCol = Cells(rowNumber, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Where `rowNumber` is partciular number of of a row.

Now, having `lastCol` we can define the range:

```
Set rng = Range(Cells(rowNumber, 17), Cells(rowNumber, lastCol))
```

Again, `rowNumber` is partciular number of of a row.

Comment: @nizarcan Then you should accept the answer (green check mark on the elft) and optionally upvote.